# How to fix the x tick label in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have some data in excel with following information

```
Rx        SD      TP         Time
-64.27  1.66    20.99   15:36:14.58
-62     1.58    29.22   15:38:50.53
-62.33  1.55    29.23   15:41:27.53
-61.17  1.33    29.26   15:44:04.54
-60.15  1.05    29.22   15:46:41.52
-62.53  1.46    29.14   15:49:18.55
-64.1   1.48    25.07   15:51:55.50
-62.45  1.52    28.91   15:54:31.51
-65.14  1.41    21.86   15:57:08.46
-63.61  2.05    20.05   15:59:44.50



.
.
.
.
-59.56  0.6    29.1     17:15:20.57
-59.71  0.68    29.1    17:17:57.58
-59.44  0.57    29.14   17:20:34.59
-59.62  0.64    29.12   17:23:11.60
-59.58  0.64    29.15   17:25:48.51
```

I have extracted the information from excel using:

```
[tp,t] = xlsread(data,xlsheet,xlrange)
```

where t stores the time values.

I have extracted each of these values of Rx, SD and TP in matlab:

```
tp_w= tp(:,3);
rx_pow= tp(:,1);
rx_err= tp(:,2);
t1=datenum(t);
```

For my graph, I need to plot TP vs time in `subplot (2,1,1)` and Rx with SD vs time in `subplot (2,1,2)`. 
Figure: I have plotted the following figure with following method.

```
a1=subplot(2,1,1)
plot(t1,tp_w,'-gd','Linewidth',1);
xlim([min(t1),max(t1)])
ylim([0,30])
set(gca,'yTick',0:1:30)
datetick('x',13) 
xlabel('Time);
ylabel('TP ');
grid on;
```

For Rx with Error I am using errobar function:

```
a2=subplot(2,1,2)
errorbar(t1,rx_pow,rx,'-rd','Linewidth',1);
xlim([min(t1),max(t1)])
ylim([-70,-53])
set(gca,'yTick',-70:0.5:-53)
datetick('x',13) 
xlabel('Time);
ylabel('Rx ');
grid on; 

linkaxes([a1,a2],'x')

hold on
```

[image]

Q1: My data starts from `15:36:15.73` and ends at `17:25:48.51`. How can make my graph start from right from `15:36:00` and end at `17:25:48.51` so that i don't have gap at start and end.

Q2:How can I add more x-tick so that I have more labels on X axis ? eg. `16:45:00...17:00:00...17:15:00` and so on

EDIT 1: Update after adding in plot function:

```
h = gca;
set(h, 'XTick', [(55200/86400):(90/86400):(63000/86400)]); 
datetick('x', 13', 'keeplimits', 'keepticks');
```

[image]

EDIT2: with necessary changes
Commenting XTick:

```
a1=subplot(2,1,1)
plot(t1,tp_w,'-gd','Linewidth',1);
xlim([min(t1),max(t1)])
% h = gca;
% set(h,'XTick',[(55100/86400):(900/86400):(62140/86400)]); 
ylim([0,30])
set(gca,'yTick',0:1:30)
datetick('x', 13,'keepticks','keeplimits');
xlabel('Time');
ylabel('TP ');
grid on;
```

[image: Commenting Xtick and using datetick('x', 13,'keepticks','keeplimits')]

Keeping datetick at last and commenting linkaxes:

```
a1=subplot(2,1,1)
plot(t1,tp_w,'-gd','Linewidth',1);
xlim([min(t1),max(t1)])
h = gca;
set(h,'XTick',[(55100/86400):(900/86400):(62140/86400)]); 
ylim([0,30])
set(gca,'yTick',0:1:30)
datetick('x', 13,'keepticks','keeplimits');
xlabel('Time');
ylabel('TP ');
grid on;
```

There is no axis:
[image: Commenting linkaxes]

The result of get(gca) (linkaxes off + datetick kept at end):

```
get(gca)
    ActivePositionProperty = outerposition
    ALim = [0 1]
    ALimMode = auto
    AmbientLightColor = [1 1 1]
    Box = off
    CameraPosition = [0.5 0.5 9.16025]
    CameraPositionMode = auto
    CameraTarget = [0.5 0.5 0.5]
    CameraTargetMode = auto
    CameraUpVector = [0 1 0]
    CameraUpVectorMode = auto
    CameraViewAngle = [6.60861]
    CameraViewAngleMode = auto
    CLim = [0 1]
    CLimMode = auto
    Color = [1 1 1]
    CurrentPoint = [ (2 by 3) double array]
    ColorOrder = [ (7 by 3) double array]
    DataAspectRatio = [1 1 1]
    DataAspectRatioMode = auto
    DrawMode = normal
    FontAngle = normal
    FontName = Helvetica
    FontSize = [10]
    FontUnits = points
    FontWeight = normal
    GridLineStyle = :
    Layer = bottom
    LineStyleOrder = -
    LineWidth = [0.5]
    MinorGridLineStyle = :
    NextPlot = replace
    OuterPosition = [0 0 1 1]
    PlotBoxAspectRatio = [1 1 1]
    PlotBoxAspectRatioMode = auto
    Projection = orthographic
    Position = [0.13 0.11 0.775 0.815]
    TickLength = [0.01 0.025]
    TickDir = in
    TickDirMode = auto
    TightInset = [0.0392857 0.0404762 0.00892857 0.0190476]
    Title = [174.006]
    Units = normalized
    View = [0 90]
    XColor = [0 0 0]
    XDir = normal
    XGrid = off
    XLabel = [175.006]
    XAxisLocation = bottom
    XLim = [0 1]
    XLimMode = auto
    XMinorGrid = off
    XMinorTick = off
    XScale = linear
    XTick = [ (1 by 11) double array]
    XTickLabel = [ (11 by 3) char array]
    XTickLabelMode = auto
    XTickMode = auto
    YColor = [0 0 0]
    YDir = normal
    YGrid = off
    YLabel = [176.006]
    YAxisLocation = left
    YLim = [0 1]
    YLimMode = auto
    YMinorGrid = off
    YMinorTick = off
    YScale = linear
    YTick = [ (1 by 11) double array]
    YTickLabel = [ (11 by 3) char array]
    YTickLabelMode = auto
    YTickMode = auto
    ZColor = [0 0 0]
    ZDir = normal
    ZGrid = off
    ZLabel = [177.006]
    ZLim = [0 1]
    ZLimMode = auto
    ZMinorGrid = off
    ZMinorTick = off
    ZScale = linear
    ZTick = [0 0.5 1]
    ZTickLabel = 
    ZTickLabelMode = auto
    ZTickMode = auto

    BeingDeleted = off
    ButtonDownFcn = 
    Children = []
    Clipping = on
    CreateFcn = 
    DeleteFcn = 
    BusyAction = queue
    HandleVisibility = on
    HitTest = on
    Interruptible = on
    Parent = [1]
    Selected = off
    SelectionHighlight = on
    Tag = 
    Type = axes
    UIContextMenu = []
    UserData = []
    Visible = on
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing the right thing to set the limits.  The problem is that datetick messes with them.

First, to change the number of ticks, use the 'XTick' property of the axes.  For example:

```
h = gca;
set(h, 'XTick', [(55800/86400):(900/86400):(63000/86400)]);  %% This should do 15-minute increments...change the "900" to the seconds value that you want for intervals
```

The tricky thing is that datetick messes with your limits and tick marks, unless you explicitly tell it not to.

```
datetick('x', 13', 'keeplimits', 'keepticks');
```

Comment: After adding following function as you suggested the graph is starting from origin but there is no axis. I have updated the graph.

Comment: Are you running the datetick() command as the very last command?  I would try it without the link axes command and see if that helps.  If not, run `get(gca)` and post the result here.

Comment: Hi, commenting XTick and only using datetick started the graph from origin with again the Xtick label was not fixed.Look the graph in edit section.

Comment: well, I'm a little surprised.  I am pretty much running your code and not getting the same result.  It looks to me like perhaps your XTick is not being set right.  If you happened to set XTick to a set of values outside the xlim, you would see exactly what you are showing...no ticks at all.  So I would step through your code one line at a time, watch how the figure changes, and after each step, run `get(gca, 'XTick')` at the command prompt to make sure your xTicks stay within range of the plot.  Sorry, I can't think of much else since I can't reproduce your problem.